# How to let users subscribe and be notified (email) when certain type of content or taxonomy is created?

Tags: 7, notifications

I would like to notify users (by email) whenever a content type or taxonomy term they subscribed to is submitted.

I thought Rules may play a role in this but can't figure out how to let them subscribe to the content type/taxonomy term

Any ideas are welcome

I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the [Subscriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module and it does exactly what I needed. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions. Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions. Users can also set an auto-subscribe function which notifies the user if anyone comments on posts they have made. Admins can turn this on by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the subscription by adding the taxonomie term to the user profile. If you don't have to many content types you could add it as a simple select list to the profile. This can be done at `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`.

As you sugested you can use Rules to get triggered about creates/updates of content or taxonomy terms. You might have to implement custom rules conditions or actions in PHP in a custom module to get exactly what you need. Check the differen [hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/7) to define your own rules conditions or actions. [hook_rules_action_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7) and [hook_rules_condition_info](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_condition_info/7) are the most interesting for you.

To lear how to build your own rules code you find many examples in Drupal core and contributed modules.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "You could do the subscription by adding the taxonomie term to the user profile" ?
Could you give a little more details on how to do that ? (I'm not a developper. I usually get things done just by installing and fiddling with modules)

Comment: See the updated. I added the path for the user profile fields. About rules: I think you cannot do this without some coding.